# Onclick not opening panel content

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello so i was trying to make show hide button but it doesn't seem to work for some reason. Im not sure whats the problem so please help me out.

```js
     var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
     var i;

     for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      acc[i].onclick = function(){
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
      }
     }
```

```css
button.accordion {
    background-color: #a5d424;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-family:"Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #2d4005;
    color: #7FFF00;
}

button.accordion:after {
    content: '\25BC'; /*02795*/
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #777;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
    content: "\25B2"; /*02796*/
    color: #7FFF00;
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}

div.panel.show {
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <button class="accordion"> Button to see panel. <button>

    <div class="panel">
       <p>TEST</p>
    </div>
    <!-- <script>
         var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
     var i;

     for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      acc[i].onclick = function(){
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
      }
     }
     </script> -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to add correct HTML.

Comment: In current code now you are just adding and removing classes that working. can you please correct html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You forgot to close the `button` tag in your HTML code. It should be `<button class="accordion"> Button to see panel. </button>`.

By the way, i see that you import jQuery in your HTML but you use vanilla JS for DOM manipulation in your JS code. Not really a problem but DOM manipulation is one of the strong points of jQuery so you may check again to see if you really need this plugin or else simply remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in html structure. You have not closed "button" tag. Change `<button> to </button>` and everything will work !